# Dependencies of function parameters

Tags: php, function, coding-style

Is it considered a bad design if a function uses the value of a parameter only if another parameter has a certain value?

Here's an example function:

```
validate_input($field_name, $validation_rule, $validation_value);
```

Here's the function in use:

```
validate_input("username", "required");
validate_input("username", "min_length", 3);
```

In the first usage example the third parameter is omitted. The second parameter has a value of "required" and that makes the third parameter irrelevant. If a third parameter is passed the function will not take it into consideration.

Does that make the design of the function bad?

Comment: This is not only not bad design, but pretty good! Everybody hates those twelve-argument-functions-of-those-I-actually-only-care-about-one in Win32API. And everybody hates XML for very annoying "features" like `required="required"` (I think that's the reason why it is `contenteditable="true"` in HTML5. So that those XML fanatics don't need to write `contenteditable="contenteditable"`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does that make the design of the function bad?

I'd say no, absolutely not.

If you document your code, mark the third parameter as optional.

In [phpDocumentor](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html), this is achieved by giving it a default value (which you need to do anyway in your case).

```
function validate_input($field_name, $validation_rule, $validation_value = null);
```

I have never come across an opinion that speaks out against this.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion and the tip! I was wondering if you could give an example of a native PHP function that has such a parameter dependency (if I may call it that).

Comment: @Emanuel yeah, I thought about adding an example from the PHP core but can't think of one off the top of my head. There are plenty of merely *optional* parameters but this case is slightly different.... I'm 99% sure I've seen this in native PHP functions, though. If I think of one, I'll post it

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make the function design bad; but you should perhaps set a default for the third parameter in your function definition, so that it isn't mandatory to call the function with a third parameter.

```
function validate_input($field_name, $validation_rule, $validation_value=null) {
    ....
}
```

**EDIT**

The setlocale() function in core PHP is possibly similar to what you want